# NSCell continuously redraws

Tags: cocoa

I have next issue:
I have subclass of `NSTextFieldCell`. In this subclass I override `drawWithFrame:` method of `NSCell` and draw custom semi-transparent visual representation. This subclass is inserted into `NSTextField`, which is inserted in semi-transparrent view. The problem was next: drawing code superimposed on each other, i.e. Cocoa continuously call `drawWithFrame:` method and continuously superimposed currently draw results on previous drawing results. How can I avoid superimposed drawing on each other? 
There are code:

```
@interface MySubclass : NSTextFieldCell
...
@end

@implementation
...
// Only this methods overrided
- (void) drawWithFrame: (NSRect)cellFrame inView: (NSView *)controlView
{
    [_someGradient drawInRect:cellFrame angle:90]; // gradient alpha is 0.5f

    NSBezierPath* path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect];
    [path setClip];

    NSShadow* shadow = [[NSShadow new] autorelease];
    // setup shadow
    [shadow set];
    [path stroke];

    [_someColor setStroke];
    [path stroke];

    [super drawWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
}
...
@end
```

Comment: Code please? It's hard to guess at what's going on.

Comment: It's enough of code? What code you need?

Comment: This short code example does not show anything that would cause a constant redraw, so either this happens in the not-shown code or outside of this cell implemenation.

Comment: There are no some extraordinary drawing here. Putting many characters and digits, as defining NSGradient or NSShadow and drawing them, to code description hasn't sense, only tangle.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. In my case, maybe will be helpful to someone, I solve the issue with calling `CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer` before and `CGContextEndTransparencyLayer` after drawing commands.